# How to check if a bucket has lifecycle configuration set using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to add rules in bucket's life cycle configurations. But before that I want to check if the target bucket has life cycle configured so that I'll add new rules to that configuration otherwise a new configuration is created. Please if anyone know how to do it, kindly share code.

Also, I've tried `get_bucket_lifecycle()` and `get_bucket_lifecycle_configurations()` but code throws exception in case if the bucket does not have life-cycle configurations. And I'm not able to escape from this error.

Comment: Calling `get-bucket-lifecycle` via the AWS CLI returned me a `NoSuchLifecycleConfiguration` error. That seems like an acceptable way to determine whether there is a lifecycle configured. Just use a try/except to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

This adds new lifecycle rules while preserving the rules of a possibly existing lifecycle configuration.

```py
import boto3
import botocore.exceptions

s3 = boto3.client("s3")

try:
    existing_rules = s3.get_bucket_lifecycle_configuration(Bucket=bucket_name)[
        "Rules"
    ]
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response["Error"]["Code"] == "NoSuchLifecycleConfiguration":
        existing_rules = []
    else:
        raise

s3.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration(
    Bucket=bucket_name,
    LifecycleConfiguration={
        "Rules": (
            existing_rules + new_rules
        )
    },
)
```